# O(1) constant c value?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

As per the coding interview book by Narasimha Karumanchi , there is a question to find the upper bound for

```
f(n) = 410
```

Logically, The Answer should be **O(1) with n0 = 1 and c = 410**

But the answer is mentioned as **O(1) with n0 = 1 and c = 1**

Is there a mistake in the answer or am I wrong here?

**Reason for this answer**

Since 410<=410*(1) for all values of n and c is 410 when considered with f(n) = 1

Comment: @AndyG If the question is to find the upper bound of function f(n) defined as f(n) = 410, then there's no concept of operations here. If you're assuming this is pseudocode, then you can talk about operations. Big-O is the upper bound of a function, it's just that for the running time of code this function is usually the number of operations.

Comment: @Dukeling Yeah, you're right about that. So does this mean the value of c should be 410 ?

Comment: @DanielIsaac Yes, it would seem that the textbook is incorrect (unless it explicitly states that we're talking about operations instead of just the function f).

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dukeling: You're right, I retract my previous comment. From a mathematical standpoint, OP is right.

Comment: Textbook is wrong. Their constant is correct if their intent is to show that f(n) = O(410). Now, O(410) = O(1), again abusing equality, but to show each one individually from the definition requires different values of c.

Comment: I think the usage of O-notation is a bit confusing here - if you are talking about upper bound of `f` function then, yes, `410` is the upper bound, as `f(x) <= 410 for all x`. If you are talking about upper bound of `f`'s time complexity, then `f = O(1)` as there is only constant number of operations (1). However `O(1) = O(410) = O(any positive constant)`, so that wouldn't matter.

Answer (score -2):

The constant 410<=410*1 for all values of n and c is 410 when considered with f(n) = 1 that is why c and input is 1

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29883564)